# Show that there is a Borel function from [0,1] to $2^ω$

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Show that there is a Borel function from [0,1] to $2^ω$. Conclude that there is a Borel function from $[0,1]^ω$ to $2^ω$. I'm not sure how to go about this. I know that a function is Borel if the preimage of open subsets of Y are Borel in X, but I don't know how to construct one. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want some additional properties for your functions to prevent simple examples like constants, right?

Comment: @martini Yes, I think so

Comment: Then you have to state the wanted properties ...

Comment: @martini I may be wrong. No additional info was given in the question. So a constant function would suffice?

Comment: Of course. Constants are Borel, even continuous.

Comment: Questions on the meaning of assigned problems should be addressed to the person who gave you the assignment.  It is not up to us to guess.

Comment: @GEdgar I wasn't asking the meaning of the assigned problem.